# Add font to website

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to add Ubuntu font to my website, I'd like to have it universal on the site so everything is in that font but I started by just adding it to my `h1` tag to see if it works, but it doesn't work. I have uploaded the font to my server.

This is my css so far:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    src: url('ubuntu/Ubuntu-R.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-weight : normal;
    margin-top: 10px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

h1 { 
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom : 0.2em;
    font-size : 3em; /* 96 / 16 */
    line-height : 1.4;
}
```

I'm probably being really stupid, as usual. I've looked at other examples but can't really see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In which directory is this css file? And in which is the font file?

Comment: Ubuntu is available on Google Fonts. I would highly recommend using that method as oppose to serving the font yourself. It's as easy as putting <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> in your header. https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Ubuntu.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved in 2 ways.

You can either add the google font cdn to the head tag of your website if already hosted or if you have active internet access, so you don't need to worry adding it locally in your folder.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Like so

Or probably your file path location is wrong

if your fonts are packed the root directory, you can easily call it like

```
src: url('Ubuntu-R.ttf') format('truetype');
```

But if it is in a folder (e.g ubuntu)

it can be `src: url('ubuntu/Ubuntu-R.ttf') format('truetype');`

But if in a very long path.. try doing something like this

```
src: url(../ubuntu/Ubuntu-R.ttf);
```

Then calling the `font-family` attribute, call just "one" name, if it is locally in a folder. like so

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  src: url(ubuntu/Ubuntu-R.ttf);
}

.myclass{
    font-family:Ubuntu; // The exact name for the @font-face
 }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as adding this line as the first line of your `style.css` or whatever you call it:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu);
```

It takes care of everything, and then you can just start using it in your css:

```
.ubuntu-font {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
}
```

If you'd like bold and italic or some other things as well, you can just go [here](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Ubuntu), pick those that you want, and copy the `@import` from section 3 in that page.

Also, with this you do not need to upload the font to your server, I don't see why everyone should upload all fonts to their server when there are several fast CDNs that already have everything there.